# SignalR Failed to load resource

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I'm actually looking to make a signalR chat. And I tried to make exactly like the Microsoft example.[link to example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr). I change the version of jquery to the version I have, but it's still not working. Here is my code :

```
namespace SignalRChat
{
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        public void Send(string name, string message)
        {
            // Call the broadcastMessage method to update clients.
            Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my startup class :

```
namespace SignalRChat
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Pour plus d'informations sur la configuration de votre application, visitez https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=316888
        }
    }
}
```

And in my index.html I just change this

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<!--Reference the SignalR library. -->
<script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Do you have a error ? How it's not working ?

Comment: @Fourat Yeah sorry I forgot to add it here the error is  : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found).

Comment: please debug with your borwser and find the request in the Network section and check the request URL